# Join overlapping ranges from two data frames in r

Tags: r, join, range

Note: This question was closed as a 'duplicate'. The solutions offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64362881/finding-close-match-from-data-frame-1-in-data-fame-2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64539945/merging-two-data-frames-by-time-range-in-r) did not answer my question.  They showed how to merge when a single entry fell within a range, I'm trying to identify overlapping ranges and joining them. Perhaps my title could have been better...

I have a main data set `main_df` with a start and end time (in seconds). I would like to see if the time range in `main_df` falls within a list of ranges in `lookup_df`, and if so, grab the value from `lookup_df`. Additionally, if the `main_df` falls within two different lookup ranges, duplicate the row so each value is represented.***

```
main_df <- tibble(start = c(30,124,161),
                end = c(80,152,185))

lookup_df <- tibble(start = c(34,73,126,141,174,221),
                       end = c(69,123,136,157,189,267),
                       value = c('a','b','b','b','b','a'))

# Do something here to get the following:

> final_df
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  start   end value notes                                      
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>                                      
1    30    80 a     ""                                         
2    30    80 b     "Duplicate because it falls within a and b"
3   124   152 b     "Falls within two lookups but both are b"  
4   161   185 b     ""
```

***Edit: Looking at the way I've structured the problem...

```
#Not actual code
left_join(main_df, lookup_df, by(some_range_join_function) %>% 
  add_rows(through_some_means)
```

Rather than having to add a new row I could flip how I'm joining them...

```
semi_join(lookup_df, main_df, by(some_range_join_function))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do some logical comparisons and then a case handling what shall happen if all are `'b'`, `'a'` and `'b'`, etc. In this way you easily could add more cases, e.g. both are `'a'`, one is `'a'`, more are `'b'` which you didn't declare in OP. The approach yields `NULL` if there are no matches which gets omitted during `rbind`.

```
f <- \(x, y) {
  w <- which((x[1] >= y[, 1] & x[1] <= y[, 2]) | (x[2] >= y[, 1] & x[1] <= y[, 2]))
  if (length(w) > 0) {
    d <- data.frame(t(x), value=cbind(y[w, 3]), notes='')
    if (length(w) >= 2) {
      if (all(d$value == 'b')) {
        d <- d[!duplicated(d$value), ]
        d$notes[1] <- 'both b'
      }
      else {
        d$notes[nrow(d)] <- 'a & b'
      }
    }
    d
  }
}

apply(main_df, 1, f, lookup_df, simplify=F) |> do.call(what=rbind)
#   start end value  notes
# 1    30  80     a       
# 2    30  80     b  a & b
# 3   124 152     b both b
# 4   161 185     b
```

---

*Data:*

```
main_df <- structure(list(start = c(2, 30, 124, 161), end = c(1, 80, 152, 
185)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

lookup_df <- structure(list(start = c(34, 73, 126, 141, 174, 221), end = c(69, 
123, 136, 157, 189, 267), value = c("a", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"a")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `fuzzyjoin::interval_join`:

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)

interval_join(main_df, lookup_df, by = c("start", "end"), mode = "inner") %>% 
  group_by(value, start.x, end.x) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  select(start = start.x, end = end.x, value)

# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Groups:   value, start, end [4]
  start   end value
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1    30    80 a    
2    30    80 b    
3   124   152 b    
4   161   185 b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foverlaps` from `data.table` for this.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(main_df) # make it a data.table if needed
setDT(lookup_df) # make it a data.table if needed

setkey(main_df, start, end) # set the keys of 'y'

foverlaps(lookup_df, main_df, nomatch = NULL) # do the lookup

#    start end i.start i.end value
# 1:    30  80      34    69     a
# 2:    30  80      73   123     b
# 3:   124 152     126   136     b
# 4:   124 152     141   157     b
# 5:   161 185     174   189     b
```

Or to get the cleaned results as end result (OP's final_df)

```
unique(foverlaps(lookup_df, main_df, nomatch = NULL)[, .(start, end, value)])

   start end value
1:    30  80     a
2:    30  80     b
3:   124 152     b
4:   161 185     b
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, based on `powerjoin`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(powerjoin)

power_left_join(
  main_df, lookup_df,
  by = ~ (.x$start <= .y$start & .x$end >= .y$end) |
    (.x$start >= .y$start & .x$start <= .y$end) | 
    (.x$start <= .y$start & .x$end >= .y$start), 
  keep = "left") %>% 
  distinct()

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   start   end value
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1    30    80 a    
#> 2    30    80 b    
#> 3   124   152 b    
#> 4   161   185 b
```

Or using `tidyr::crossing`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

crossing(main_df, lookup_df,
        .name_repair = ~ c("start", "end", "start2", "end2", "value")) %>% 
  filter((start <= start2 & end >= end2) |
         (start >= start2 & start <= end2) | (start <= start2 & end >= start2)) %>% 
  select(-start2, -end2) %>% 
  distinct()

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   start   end value
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1    30    80 a    
#> 2    30    80 b    
#> 3   124   152 b    
#> 4   161   185 b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fuzzyjoin` package to join based on intervals with the `fuzzyjoin::interval_*_join()` functions.

I'll be using an inner join, because if you use a semi join like you propose, you will loose the value col and get just 3 rows.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

fuzzyjoin::interval_inner_join(lookup_df, main_df, by = c("start", "end"), type = "any")
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   start.x end.x value start.y end.y
#>     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1      34    69 a          30    80
#> 2      73   123 b          30    80
#> 3     126   136 b         124   152
#> 4     141   157 b         124   152
#> 5     174   189 b         161   185
```

As you can see, the `fuzzy_inner_join()` preserves the by cols from both tables, since they are not the same in a fuzzy join. Also, we still have separate rows for those cases in `main_df` that match multiple cases in `lookup_df`. Thus, we do some cleanup of the joined table:

```r
interval_inner_join(lookup_df, main_df, 
                    by = c("start", "end"), 
                    type = "any") |> 
  select(-ends_with(".x")) |> # remove lookup interval cols
  distinct() |> # remove duplicate
  rename_with(str_remove, ends_with(".y"), "\\.y") # remove suffixes from col names
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   value start   end
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a        30    80
#> 2 b        30    80
#> 3 b       124   152
#> 4 b       161   185
```

Finally, a clarification of terminology: In your question you state you want to join based on the interval from `main_df` falling *within* the interval from `lookup_df`. This is possible by using `type = "within"` in `interval_*_join()`. But based on the examples you provide, it appears you want to join based on *any overlap*. This can be done with `type = "any"`, but it is the default, so you don't need to specify it.