# Calculate the mean based on a dates and hours

Tags: r, dataframe, average

I have two dataframes,

I would like to obtain the average of speed variables (data1 dataframe)  for the 3 hours preceding the date in my dataframe 2 (data2 dataframe)

For example i would like the mean of the speed between the date 2021-02-15 01:00:00 and the date find in my dataframe 2: 2021-02-15 04:00:00 (- 3 hours);
an other example is between the 2021-02-15 07:00:00 GMT and the 2021-02-15 10:00:00...

Here is my two dataframes:

```
Speed <- c(7,9,9,4,2,5,2,NA,1,14,3,4,10,9,34,14,25)

Date <- c("2021-02-15 01:00:00 GMT","2021-02-15 02:00:00 GMT","2021-02-15 03:00:00 GMT","2021-02-15 04:00:00 GMT", "2021-02-15 05:00:00 GMT" ,"2021-02-15 06:00:00 GMT","2021-02-15 07:00:00 GMT","2021-02-15 08:00:00 GMT", "2021-02-15 09:00:00 GMT","2021-02-15 10:00:00 GMT","2021-02-15 11:00:00 GMT" ,"2021-02-15 12:00:00 GMT","2021-02-15 13:00:00 GMT","2021-02-15 14:00:00 GMT", "2021-02-15 15:00:00 GMT","2021-02-15 16:00:00 GMT", "2021-02-15 17:00:00 GMT")

Date <-as.POSIXlt(Date,tz="GMT",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

data1 <- data.frame(Speed, Date)


search <- as.Date(c("2021-02-15 04:00:00","2021-02-15 10:00:00","2021-02-15 17:00:00"))
search <-as.POSIXlt(search ,tz="GMT",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

data2 <- data.frame(search)
```

How can I do?

I know lubridate is a good library for working on dates and I would like to find a solution using it, but I couldn't figure out how to do.

My expected output will be:

```
Dates                   average Speed
2021-02-15 04:00:00     average speed between this date and -3hours
2021-02-15 10:00:00     average speed between this date and -3hours
2021-02-15 17:00:00     average speed between this date and -3hours
```

I have a big dataset

Comment: You included the [tag:datatable] tag which is ambiguous, often referring to a .NET or javascript library. I suspect you may have intended R's `data.frame`, though you already listed [tag:dataframe]; some use it instead of [tag:data.table] for R's `data.table` package, but your code does not suggest that package, so I'm going to assume you're just looking for an R solution to something sitting in one or more `data.frame` objects. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with a combination of

- non-equi joins

  - [finding close match from data frame 1 in data fame 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64362881/3358272)
  - [Merging two data frames by time range in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64539945/3358272))
- summarize by group

  - [Calculate the mean by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272)
  - [How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/3358272)
  - [Apply several summary functions (sum, mean, etc.) on several variables by group in one call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12064202/3358272)

Unfortunately, your `data2` all occur *before* all samples in `data1` (and are all the same values). I'll use my own `data2a` to demonstrate.

```r
data2a <- data.frame(search = data1$Date[c(2, 5, 9, 17)])
data2a
#                search
# 1 2021-02-15 02:00:00
# 2 2021-02-15 05:00:00
# 3 2021-02-15 09:00:00
# 4 2021-02-15 17:00:00
```

I'll use `dplyr` to demonstrate the non-equi join and summarization:

```r
library(dplyr) # dplyr_1.1 or newer
data2a %>%
  mutate(id = row_number(), search_m3 = search - 3600*3) %>%
  left_join(data1, join_by(between(y$Date, x$search_m3, x$search))) %>%
  summarize(avg = mean(Speed, na.rm = TRUE), .by = c(id, search))
#   id              search       avg
# 1  1 2021-02-15 02:00:00  8.000000
# 2  2 2021-02-15 05:00:00  6.000000
# 3  3 2021-02-15 09:00:00  2.666667
# 4  4 2021-02-15 17:00:00 20.500000
```

Validation:

- `2021-02-15 02:00:00` (including from `23:00` the night prior) contains just two values, 7 and 9, average is `8`;
- `2021-02-15 05:00:00` (from `02:00:00`) includes four values (because this is 3 hours *inclusive*): 9, 9, 4, and 2, the average is `6`;
- `2021-02-15 09:00:00` includes four values: 5, 2, `NA`, and 1, `mean(c(5,2,NA,1), na.rm=TRUE)` is `2.67`; and
- `2021-02-15 17:00:00` includes four values: 9, 34, 14, 25, `mean(c(9, 34, 14, 25))` is `20.5`.

Walk-through:

- I define `id` so that we have an unambiguous way to return to the individual rows from `data2a`; in *this* case, we could have used `search` as the key, but I've had non-equi join situations where there are legitimate duplicates in one of the valued terms, so I tend to use this unambiguous mechanism to return to the correct order and such;
- `search_m3` is "search minus 3 (hours)", most (all?) non-equi join mechanisms in R need both ends as clear variables;
- `left_join` is one of a few merge/join variables (see [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272), [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272), (data.table) [Left join using data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34598139/3358272)), resulting in at least `nrow(data2a)` rows, likely (in this case certainly) more rows in an expansion;
- `join_by` (recent in dplyr) allows us to define the behavior; here I'm using `between(..., search_m3, search)`, though one could also have used `join_by(search_m3 < Date, search >= Date)` for a left-open join (so that 5am includes data *after* 2am but not 2am itself)
- `summarize` using the `.by=` grouping field returns just the `.by` variables and the one calculated field

The summarize-by-group is easily done in all dialects of R (base, `dplyr`, and `data.table`), but the non-equi join is not done "easily" in base R; it can also be done fairly directly in `dplyr` (shown above), `data.table`, or with the `fuzzyjoin` package or anything that supports SQL (`sqldf`, `RSQLite`, and any "more-formal" database connector).

---

Using your added `Dates`-including frame, I'll modify this code in two ways:

- `Dates` instead of `search` (though I still use `search_m3` as my temporary variable); and
- left-open comparison, so when looking at (say) `10:00:00`, we include times `08:00:00`, `09:00:00`, and `10:00:00`, but notably not `07:00:00`; feel free to play with `>`/`>=`/`<`/`<=` for your preferences of left/right open/closed-ness.

```r
data2b <- structure(list(Dates = structure(c(1613361600, 1613383200, 1613408400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
data2b %>%
  mutate(id = row_number(), search_m3 = Dates - 3600*3) %>%
  left_join(data1, join_by(search_m3 < Date, Dates >= Date)) %>%
  summarize(avg = mean(Speed, na.rm = TRUE), .by = c(id, Dates))
#   id               Dates       avg
# 1  1 2021-02-15 04:00:00  7.333333
# 2  2 2021-02-15 10:00:00  7.500000
# 3  3 2021-02-15 17:00:00 24.333333
```